# python win32com client, how to switch between different installed versions of an application?

Tags: python, com, win32com

I am using the win32com client to automate a task in another application (of which I have multiple versions installed). It seems that if I use e.g.:

`win32com.client.Dispatch('myApplication')`

It automatically connects to the latest installed version of `myApplication`. Is it possible to somehow switch to the other (older) version?

More generically, how does the `Dispatch` "know" which application to tie to the string `'myApplication'`, and how do I change it? Is it possible to do that through win32com, or do I need to modify registry entries or something?